# Search for key value in JSON and print value from different key

Tags: bash, jq

I have following JSON file:

```
{  
   "data":[  
      {  
         "id":"34c4s5f7-175f-480a-adff-d8d0bef4e8c4",
         "name":"test",
         "organizationId":"7er337a-714c-4043-90b1-6a4e7we82d87",
         "isProduction":false,
         "type":"test",
         "clientId":"6d4720062eab494c45ewedaa78de1"
      },
      {  
         "id":"4856a92-9e46-4430-aac7-6ed8674569f",
         "name":"dev",
         "organizationId":"7er337a-714c-4043-90b1-6a4e7we82d87",
         "isProduction":false,
         "type":"sandbox",
         "clientId":"bs34dea7749494daa8deert908bcd9"
      }
   ],
   "total":2
}
```

My requirement is to find records where key name is `dev` and then print the id key.

I have come across

```
awk -F: '$1~/"name"/{l=$2} l~/dev/ && $1 ~ /id/ {sub(/,/,"",$2);print $2}'
```

but this prints key value which appears in subsequent lines for the matched key. I need to find the value which is before the matched key.

Comment: Why are you using `awk` for JSON parsing? Use the `jq` - the lightweight JSON parser

Comment: This would be part of jenkins build process. Can we implement jq in jenkins?

Comment: Yes you could install `jq` in your nodes

Comment: Is https://github.com/arakelian/java-jq relevant here?

Answer (score 2):

Using `jq`:

```
jq '.data[] | select(.name == "dev") | .id' file
```

Use `-r` option if you want raw data (without quote).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand jq does the job. But I have some limitations while setting up jq in my jenkins server. Is there any way it can be achieved in bash script using awk/sed/grep/etc would be great. Thanks again.

Comment: @W- awk/sed/grep/etc are not JSON parser. You should not use them to perform such a task. If `jq` can't be use, go for higher level languages like perl/python/etc and rely on their JSON library.

Comment: gawk has an extension for parsing JSON. see [link](http://gawkextlib.sourceforge.net/json/json.html)

Answer (score 0):

Under reasonable assumptions, you could probably get away with the following, or something very much like it:

```
awk '
  function check() { 
    if (flag && id) {
      sub(".[^:]*:\"","",id); sub(/.,$/,"",id); 
      print id; flag=id="";
    }
  }
  $1 ~ /},?/ { check(); next; }
  /^ *"id":/ { id=$0; next; }
  /^ *"name":"dev"/ {flag=1} '
```